# Filtro de busqueda en PHP

Tags: php

La cuestión es esta tengo un sistema de gestion en el cual hay un módulo de clientes en este tengo que añadir un filtro que busque por mascota,compra,fecha de compra.

Mi problema:

> Radica cuando tengo que armar el query con estas variables porque tengo que identificar cuales estan vacias y de acuerdo a eso ir armando el query, yo sé que mediante la funcion "`empty`" identifico cual esta vacia entonces:

El query es siguiente:

```
SELECT * 
        FROM        clientes a
        left join factura f on a.cedula=f.cedula
        left join gestion g on g.idcliente=a.id
        WHERE ( ".$s1."
             ".$s2."
             ".$s3."
             )
```

donde $s1,$s2,$s3 deben de ser las variables del filtro, si lo hago por uno solo si me sale pero si lo hago por mas de uno me sale error

Comment: pero que tipo de condicional piensas poner en el where, o mejor dicho que vlores traen $s1,$s2,$s3

Answer (score 1):

ya lo resolví muchas gracias por la ayuda tuve que poner algunas condicionales y me quedo asi:

```
if($mascota != 1):
        $s1=" a.mascota = '".$mascota."'";
        else:
        $s1=" ";
    endif;
    if($compra != 1 && $mascota == 1):
        $s2="f.producto like '%".$compra."%'";
    else:   if ($compra != 1) :
            $s2="and f.producto like '%".$compra."%'";
            else:
            $s2=" ";
            endif;
    endif;
    if($fecha_gestion != 1 && $mascota == 1 && $compra == 1):
        $s3="CAST(g.dateat AS DATE) = '".$fecha_gestion."'";
    else:   if ($fecha_gestion != 1) :
            $s3="and CAST(g.dateat AS DATE) = '".$fecha_gestion."'";
            else:
            $s3=" ";
            endif;
    endif;
    if($fecha_compra != 1  && $mascota == 1 && $compra == 1 && $fecha_gestion == 1):
        $s3="f.fecha = '".$fecha_compra."'";
    else:   if ($fecha_compra != 1):
            $s3="and f.fecha = '".$fecha_compra."'";
            else:
            $s3=" ";
            endif;
    endif;
```

el problema era que tenia que identificar cuando añadirle el and en el where pero con un poco de logica lo resolví, muchas gracias

Comment: Nol olvides considerar marcar alguna respuesta como aceptada y asi los demás nos enteramos cual fue la solución

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puede hacer una condicion antes de y dependiendo de eso hacer darle un valor a los 
$s1 $s2 $s3

ejemplo

```
if( tengo_una_mascota  ){
$s1 = "mascota = nombre_de_la_mascota";
}else{
$s1 = "";
}
```

y de esta manera si no tienes datos para hacer la condicion solo concatenas espacios en blanco en la parte del WHERE